# CSS padding for safari and jQuery doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

In Chrome and ff, My menu has a padding ... and i see that's working on both browsers.. But when i view it in Safari.. the padding is not there.

```
.jplnav li {
padding: 15px 0;
}
```

My next problem is... i want to use bxslider. I followed their instructions on how to install it but it's not working at my end.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/query.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>My Slider</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Goodbye</li>
      <li>Yes</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.bxslider.min.js:10   
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:19 
 Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: you should split this into two questions. because, you know ... its two different questions.

Comment: yeah, can i still do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `http:`  at the start of the jquery script request.

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
```

And

you don't have anything in you html with a class of jplnav.  Unless it's added by the slider (which isn't running because jQuery isn't loaded).

Comment: sorry, i clicked the wrong button, i retracted it. and using just `//` will work because it takes the existing method of the page (`http` vs `https`) and applies it appropriately. i use this regularly.

Comment: Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js is the error message, so adding http will fix it.

Comment: the only way it wouldn't have worked is if you are not running a localhost, and instead are developing just with standard files (because everything then is using `file:` instead of `http:`). you won't have the same issue when you run these pages on an actual server.

Answer (score 2):

Your padding problem is caused by so called "user-agent-stylesheets"

for example when you look at an unformatted ul in the browser, you can see that the li´s have a margin to the left etc.

so first you have to reset the ul globaly like

```
ul li {
   padding:0;
   margin:0
}

/* And after that */

.jplnav li {
   padding: 15px 0;
 }
```

it´s a guess but i think it will fix it

and on your second question i think you wrote the answer

> Failed to load resource
>   file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

so make sure youre you use the correct url...

Comment: adding the ul li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
} on the top of my css lines didn't work.. the padding only doesnt work in safari